# How to keep background gps service alive

Tags: android, background, gps

I'm trying to have a background gps location listener as a service that can be used by all activities in my app. It should also be scanning for locations until I "kill" it. However I realized that after a couple of hours the gps service gets killed and I can't get anymore locations.

How do I keep this service alive (the locationManager and location listener at least) until I want it off?

Thanks

```
public class GPS extends IntentService {
    public static LocationListener loc_listener = null;
    public static LocationManager locationManager = null;

    public GPS() {
        super("GPS");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (loc_listener == null) {
            loc_listener = new LocationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                        Bundle extras) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            };
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                0, loc_listener);
    }

    public static void killGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null && loc_listener != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(loc_listener);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However I realized that after a couple of hours the gps service gets killed and I can't get anymore locations.

First, it is an exceptionally bad idea to keep GPS powered on all of the time, as the user's battery life will suffer greatly. Your application needs to offer tremendous value (e.g., Google Navigation) to warrant this power cost.

Second, never register a listener from an `IntentService`. Once `onHandleIntent()` ends, the service shuts down... but you leak your registered listener. This effectively keeps a background thread going. However, since you have no active components, Android eventually will terminate your process.

Comment: This is for testing, I will customize it later to make it more battery efficient. If registering a listener from an IntentService is not good, should I open the listener from an activity? If so how can I set it up so that I can keep it on for a few mins before recording a location and then turning it off?

Comment: @Sean: Use a regular `Service` in that case. Register the listener in `onStartCommand()`. When the fix arrives, or when some timeout condition occurs, unregister the listener and call `stopSelf()`. You can see an example of this with my `LocationPoller` component (https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll), though that is designed for cases where there it not necessarily an activity.

Comment: Hi I tried to implement your example but I can never seem to get the the locationReceiver class. In the log I see a FileNotFoundException error (permission denied), perhaps this is the reason I'm not receiving anything? Anyways if you have any ideas of whats going on i'd greatly appreciate any help. Thanks